# change static UITableViewCell background color inside a UIPopoverController xcode5

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, xcode5, uipopovercontroller, ios7.1

I'm developing an app for iOS7.1 in Xcode 5

And I want to change tableview cell's background color at the final row to look like this

[image]

but when I call this UITableViewController inside a UIPopoverController I get this:

[image]

Somehow my tableview cell lost it's original background color

this is my code:

```
//iPad Popover Section
        if (!resultBTPopover || !resultBTPopover.popoverVisible)
        {
            ResultadosBalanceTransferVC *controller   = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ResultadosBalanceTransferVC"];
            //controller.delegate             = self;
            controller.title                = @"Resultados";
            controller.amountValue          = self.amountTextfield.text;
            controller.promoRateValue       = self.promoRateTextfield.text;
            controller.normalRateValue      = self.normalRateTextfield.text;
            controller.otherBankRateValue   = self.otherBankRateTextfield.text;
            controller.termValue            = self.termTextfield.text;



            navController                  = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:controller];
            navController.toolbarHidden     = FALSE;

            NSDictionary *textAtributesDictionaryTitle = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                          UIColorFromRGB(toolbarTintColor),  NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
                                                          [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-BoldCond" size:19.0f], NSFontAttributeName,
                                                          nil];

            [navController.navigationBar setTitleTextAttributes:textAtributesDictionaryTitle];

            resultBTPopover   = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:navController];


            [resultBTPopover presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(self.view.center.x - (self.view.center.x * .2734), self.view.center.y - (self.view.center.y * .6510), 300, 400)
                                             inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:0
                                           animated:YES];
        }
        else{
            [resultBTPopover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
            resultBTPopover = nil;
        }
    }
```

how to get my original tableview cell colors???

thanks in advance for the support

---

**EDIT:** I'll put method proposed by Plokstorm

ResultsCell.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ResultsCell : UITableViewCell

@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *label1;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *label2;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *label3;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *label4;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *label5;

@end
```

on STORYBOARD I did this:

[image]

all of them changed to ResultsCell custom class

[image]

linked all the properties with visual labels of the UITableViewCell

on CODE I did this for testing:

ResultadosBalanceTransferVC.m

```
#import "ResultsCell.h"
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    ResultsCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[ResultsCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault  reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    }

    if (indexPath.row == 2){
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        cell.label1.text = @"Pago Total";
    }

    return cell;

}
```

and... still getting same result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Show us your

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

You can change a cell background with `cell.backgroundColor`.

Comment: I didn't have that method implemented since this is a static tableview controller, I added it and I get this error: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:' gonna update my code to show you the method implementation

Answer (score 0):

Try that:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault  reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    }
    if (indexPath.row == 2)
          cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];


    return cell;
}
```

Comment: done, I added your code, it works but it also erases all my labels, gonna update my post to see the result

Answer (score 0):

You need to change cell class with it in storyboard.

If you don't create a cell class, you should create an object which extends UITableViewCell. Then you can add its property.

```
@interface ResultsCell : UITableViewCell
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *lYourFirstLabel;
```

---

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    ResultsCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[ResultsCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault  reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    }
    if (indexPath.row == 2)
          cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
          [cell.lYourFirstLabel setText:@"hello"];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: I did what you're suggesting but I get same result, gonna update my comment with all the steps I did jut to know if I missed something